# Session Timeout Unexpected Value 9999

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I know the range for Session Timeout is 1-9999, default to (10 or 600?).

My web.config sets `SessionState timeout="5"`

I have some Razor injecting JavaScript with `@Session.Timeout`

The Razor evaluates to `5` as expected, everywhere that I can troubleshoot.

Except in Production.  If I view the HTML of my production website, the place where the Razor `@Session.Timeout` sits shows `9999`!!?

The Web.Config on the **Build-Server** shows `SessionState timeout="5"`, and that Web.Config is copied directly to the prod location(s) in automated builds (which I don't have access to.)

Lastly: There are precisely **zero** calls in the code to alter `HttpSessionState.Anything`.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Without being able to see the web.config in production, any answer you get is a guess. Also, the fact "Web.Config is copied directly to the prod location(s) in automated builds" sounds wrong; things like database connection strings, the compilation key, etc. should be changed as the site is deployed.

Comment: They are changed in the Release Transform onto the Build-Server.  When Release-Management Client says "Go-Ahead!", it is supposedly copied directly as-is into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something overwrite your application web.config

can you check [the config files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.140).aspx) that come before and after your web.config

first one would be the **Machine.config** `systemroot\Microsoft .NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Machine.config`

second one would be **ApplicationHost.config** `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`

and third the root **Web.config** `systemroot\Microsoft .NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Web.config`

also you should check [Tip 2: Understand how your site Web.config inherits its settings](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides) that simplified it

Comment: Fredou, thank you for the reply.  I have requested the server team send me Machine and AppHost from all nodes of our servers.  Of course it is unlikely that there is an issue there, but it's the only new direction I have received.  Let's see how it pans out.

Comment: I checked everything outside of the actual production web.config and couldn't find anything.  Though they were all very legitimate and the best answer to the problem.  Unfortunately, after being the squeaky tire, I finally came to find the web.config had 9999 hardcoded as the timeout.  I hate not being able to trust the process, but that's what this amounts to.  It presents a problem, and now I just have to help solve the problem of bettering the process!  =-D

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check/try:

1. Check the ApplicationHost.config file to see if session timeout is being defined there.
2. If you are using forms authentication check this section and see if there is a value out of place:

   ```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms timeout="9999" ... />
   </authentication>
   ```
3. Is anything clever going on in `Session_Start` in global.asax? Some people like to play around with the session here when it first starts.

Comment: Thanks!  That is a legit place to check.  +1 for adding information.